# how to save counter on lcd in mikroc

Tags: microcontroller, pic, lcd, memory

My code is about button counter  .which appear on lcd 2x16 .pic18f46k20 .i want when i turn power off and turn on it again it should show the last number it count .
how to make data saved in pic and lcd when i turn off the power?

Answer (score 1):

You could add non volatile memory to your project, but I think that would be overkill since the amount of space would be more than necessary. You could also write the data to EEPROM, but since there are a finite number of writes to it, I don't know if you would want to use it. Third option, you could add a real time clock, just to keep the memory alive. You would still keep it powered, but just in a sleeping state so the memory is retained.